# IIS 6 404 error calling on localhost

Tags: iis-6, http-status-code-404

I'm kinda desperate here

I have a Windows 2003 Server and when I try to call http://localhost I get a 404 error

I have localhost configured to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ and whatever file I create there it always shows a 404

This is what I see on the log file

```
2010-07-22 14:54:06 W3SVC1 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+SV1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 404 0 3
```

I tried restarting IIS with no luck, the eventvwr shows no error whatsoever.

Please any light will be appeciated

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the binding for 127.0.0.1:80 is configured properly in the web site properties. You need to tell IIS to respond to requests to 127.0.0.1 (localhost's IP address).

[image: Use the values 127.0.0.1 and localhost, respectively.]

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that any URL, even to a specific file like http://localhost/myfile.htm, gives a 404, or just the default URL that you give in the question?

The first thing I would check, assuming you're just talking about the http://localhost URL, is the Default Document option on the web site (right-click, properties, Documents tab).  1) is Enable Default Document checked? and 2) do you have a file in your document root named the same as one of the file names in the list?